# Need help finding the nearest integer in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Hi guys so I need help figuring out how to do the following task:

Modify the function to return the average age of everyone in the people array, rounded to the nearest integer.

```
var total = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    total += people[i];
}
var avg = total / people.length;
}

/* Do not modify code below this line */

const examplePeopleArray = [
  { name: 'John', age: 19 },
  { name: 'Jack', age: 21 },
  { name: 'Jane', age: 22 }
];

console.log(getRoundedAverageAge(examplePeopleArray), '<-- should be 21');
```

So this is what I've implemented right now:

```
for(var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    total += people[i];
}
var avg = total / people.length;
}
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how to calculate the integer.

Is there something that I'm forgetting to add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function getRoundedAverageAge(people)
{
  var total = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
      total += people[i].age;
  }
  var avg = total / people.length;
  return Math.round(avg);
}

/* Do not modify code below this line */

const examplePeopleArray = [
  { name: 'John', age: 19 },
  { name: 'Jack', age: 21 },
  { name: 'Jane', age: 22 }
];

console.log(getRoundedAverageAge(examplePeopleArray));
```

Comment: Hi Silentw my output should be 21. I get this message "Nan <--- should be 21" in output. How do I achieve that?

Comment: ahh I see I was missing the .age property thanks!

Comment: @KobeRichardson-Jones if this answers your question, don't forget to accept the answer by clicking the tick sign